# Proc Tabulate in SAS: repeating class names for each row

Tags: sas

If I want to summarize my data by class1 and class2 and show the sum of var1, what's the simplest code to get an output that looks like:

```
    Class1  Class2  Var1Sum
    a       x       123
    a       y        34
    a       z       990
    b       y        98
```

I tried the below:

```
proc tabulate data=datasetname;
    class class1 class2;
    var var1;
    table class1,class2,var1*(SUM);
run;
```

which gets me:

```
    Class1  Class2  Var1Sum
    a       x       123
            y        34
            z       990
    b       y        98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `PROC SUMMARY` to create a result dataset and then use `PROC PRINT` to create your report:

```
proc summary nway data=mydata;
   class class1 class2;
   var var1;
   output out=summary(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=Var1Sum;
run;
proc print data=summary;
run;
```

I don't use `PROC TABULATE` myself, but if you are looking for a reporting-only solution, read up on the `PROC REPORT` procedure.  It might also do what you want.

Comment: Can you edit this so that the sum of each variable is in one row? Trying to follow this format to create a Pivot Table in Excel in the end, and this doesn't work so well.

Answer (score 1):

I had to assume your data...but [PROC REPORT](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/242-2012.pdf) is good at summarizing data. It has many options to do what you need.

```
data have;
 input class1 $ class2 $ VarSum;
 datalines;
a       x       1
a       x       1
a       x       1
a       y       1
a       y       1
a       z       1
a       z       1
a       z       1
a       z       1
a       z       1
b       y       1
b       y       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       x       1
b       z       1
b       z       1
b       z       1
b       z       1
;

proc report data=have nowd;
 column class1 class2 varsum;

 define class1 / group;
 define class2 / group;
 define varsum / sum;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

TABULATE won't print the class1 group out repeatedly, as far as I know.  Even Report won't, by default. You'd have to print each row out using COMPUTE blocks I think if you want that in one piece.

You can however get it out to a dataset as you want:

```
ods output table=mydata(keep=class1 class2 varsum_sum);
proc tabulate data=have;
class class1 class2;
var varsum;
tables class1*class2,varsum*sum;
run;
ods output close;
```

Then print that dataset.  Tabulate or Summary are both going to do roughly the same thing here, use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Actually it will print it if you say ods output table=mydata; rather than specifying the keep because it will depend on what summaries you asked for so if you do want to keep certain ones then it will be ods output table=mydata(keep=class1 class2 varsum_sum N mean etc);

Answer (score 0):

I used the above answer and it didn't fully work for my application. This is what worked. NOTE:N PCTN in keep statement will change depending on your variable:

```
    ods output table=mydata(keep=class1 class2 N PctN);
    proc tabulate data=have;
    class class1 class2;
    tables class1*class2,(N PCTN);
    run;
    ods output close;
```

what I would do is just output it to mydata and see which columns you need to keep rather than doing it in blind.

```
ods output table=mydata;
    proc tabulate data=have;
    class class1 class2;
    tables class1*class2,(N PCTN)/noprintmiss;
    run;
    ods output close;
```